# authentication/login-callback works locally , but does not work on staging

Tags: blazor, aws-amplify

I am trying to develop C# Blazor Web assembly App. I have used AWS Amplify for Hosting (kind of Azure Static Web App). I have used Cognito Provider. I am seeing the problem when running on AWS Amplify.

It works fine when
"RedirectUri": "https://localhost:5001/authentication/login-callback".

But it does not work when

"RedirectUri": "https://main.d3ldgs2wl4uo09ef.amplifyapp.com/authentication/login-callback".

It starts with "Authorizing" and then stuck in "Completing login...".

The Error in F12:

Request URL: https://main.d3ldgs2wl4uo09ef.amplifyapp.com/authentication/login-callback/
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 404
Remote Address: 108.139.1.128:443
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Please help me.

Comment: I have noticed that on staging parameters are NOT added. For example :
https://main.d3ldgs2wl4uo09ef.amplifyapp.com/authentication/login-callback/

But locally parameters are added. For example:
https://localhost:5001/authentication/login-callback?code=ad067f86-fce1-4838-8e2d-ccfcc01c2964&state=f92afe633fbc431c994e4037541c7f21

I do not know what to do so that it works in staging. Any help will be greatly appreciated.